# Combine multiple lines of c code in bash script

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have C code where developers splitted lines different way:

```
if (x > 0) {
    syslog(
           LOG_DEBUG,
           "x > 0"
          );
} else {
    syslog(LOG_ERR,
           "error");
}
```

Result I need is:

```
if (x > 0) {
    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "x > 0");
} else {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "error");
}
```

Whitespaces don't matter much, the main task is to have syslog() calls in one line. The best I could do was:

```
sed -i -n '/syslog(.*,$/,/.*)/{:a;N;$!ta;s/\n//;p};/syslog(.*,$/!p' file.c
```

But it duplicated some lines of code. What I did wrong? How to do it properly? Scripting language doesn't matter - sed/awk/perl...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/syslog\(\K[^)]+/$&=~s|\s+| |gr/ge' file.c
if (x > 0) {
    syslog( LOG_DEBUG, "x > 0" );
} else {
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "error");
}
```

- `-0777` slurp entire file
- `syslog\(\K` positive lookbehind for string `syslog(`
- `[^)]+` get all non `)` characters

  - `$&=~s|\s+| |gr` on the matched string, replace all white-space characters with single space
- Use `perl -i -0777 -pe` for inplace editing
- Further reading: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also it works with double quotes which allows to replace "syslog" with variable and do it in bash 'for' loop for different C calls.

Comment: @Andrey, instead of bash, you can use array in perl... `perl -0777 -pe 'BEGIN{@calls=("syslog","foo")} foreach $f (@calls){s/$f\(\K[^)]+/$&=~s|\s+| |gr/ge}'`

Comment: Try that when the error string is `"bad (or worse) situation"` to see one way it can fail. Don't write regexps to try to understand C code as you cannot do that job robustly, just use a tool that understands the specific C variant/standard the code is written in - there's plenty of them around.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a [C beautifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=C+beautifier&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for this instead of trying to approximate C syntax with regexps. For example using `indent` as it just happens to be available on my cygwin installation:

```
$ cat tst.c
if (x > 0) {
    syslog(
           LOG_DEBUG,
           "x > 0"
          );
} else {
    syslog(LOG_ERR,
           "error");
}

$ indent -br tst.c

$ cat tst.c
if (x > 0) {
  syslog (LOG_DEBUG, "x > 0");
}
else {
  syslog (LOG_ERR, "error");
}
```

There are several C beautifiers (`indent`, `cb`, `uncrustify`, etc.) with various options to understand various C (and sometimes C++) standards and format code as you like.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a problem and you choose to solve it with a regular expression, you end up having two problems...

```
package soanswer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class SOAnswer
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
    List<String> input = new LinkedList<>();
    String line = null;
    String previousline = null;
    while ((line = b.readLine()) != null)
    {
      if (line.indexOf("syslog(") >= 0)
      {
        previousline = line;
      }
      else
      {
        if (previousline == null)
          input.add(line);
        else
        {
          previousline = previousline + line;
          if (line.indexOf(");") >= 0)
          {
            input.add(previousline);
            previousline = null;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (String l: input)
      System.out.println(l);
  }  
}
```

I know, it's a lot more code than a regular expression, but it's a lot more readable. Any coder can understand it even if he does not know Java. Also keep in mind Java is very verbose, the same in a scripting language usually results in much fewer lines.